# How to change scrollbar direction from right to left?

Tags: jquery

I searched through the jquery scroll and internet but i didn't find any solution
to change scrollbar of my web page from right to left.
even i typed in css html{direction: rtl} but it also not worked.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: Can you give any example, or can you explain it more widely?

Comment: I am currently developing a database for a company they use two languages one is english (ltr) and another is Dari(rtl) language so when I change the language from english to dari i want that my scrollbars should also move from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, this shall work:

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

However this is vendor-specific. I'm not aware of a cross-browser solution. Also I doubt that it is a good idea to do this, since web users (no matter of LTR or RTL) are used to having scrollbars on the right side of the browser window.

There may be an OS-specific setting to change that. Also, Firefox allows to configure the scrollbar in the `about:config` advanced configuration (see layout.scrollbar), but you can't control that via Javascript. In previous versions Firefox also switched the scrollbar layout automatically depending on the language setting (e.g. for Hebrew), but I'm not sure if that is still the case.